# Vuex Mutations and Airbnb eslint

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am unsing [Airbnb Eslint](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) on my Vuejs project (using Vue-cli). And one of the rules is [no-param-reassign](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--reassign-params). In order to control the state (using Vuex), one must use mutations/ actions:

**Rules conflict**

```
mutations: {
    increase: (state) => {
        state.counter++;
    }
}
```

**After changes according to rules**

```
mutations: {
    increase: (state) => {
        const thisState = state;
        thisState.coutner++;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to write the statement above and not breaking eslint rules?

**Solution** *(thanks to [Cobaltway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3548338/cobaltway)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44658727/6665785))*

Add `'state'` to the `ignorePropertyModificationsFor` to the rules.

Comment: Yuck! I would turn that rule off. Remember to choose appropriate style guides for your project.

Comment: @craig_h Yeah, i know that looks really bad. Usually I use a standard style, but decided to try an airbnb one. I'll have to turn-off this rule then.

Comment: You may not have to completely turn the rule off. See my addition.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, sorry.

> Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue, when we mutate the
>   state, Vue components observing the state will update automatically.
>   This also means Vuex mutations are subject to the same reactivity
>   caveats when working with plain Vue [...]

Source: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

It does mean that you **must** mutate the parameter to get any change into your actual state. The only solution there is to turn off that rule.

**Addendum:**

I may have a better solution. Note that this is the actual rule as enforced by [their ESLint](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/best-practices.js):

```
'no-param-reassign': ['error', {
  props: true,
  ignorePropertyModificationsFor: [
    'acc', // for reduce accumulators
    'e', // for e.returnvalue
    'ctx', // for Koa routing
    'req', // for Express requests
    'request', // for Express requests
    'res', // for Express responses
    'response', // for Express responses
    '$scope', // for Angular 1 scopes
  ]
}],
```

You may add `'state'` to the `ignorePropertyModificationsFor` array, so you won't encounter error when modifying your state properties.

Comment: wow, this is awesome, just tried and it works perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: you can use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Vue.set uses the same reactiveSetter function ([Reference](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0b31647c41b0c916d40b962723b1de06672d0e01/src/core/observer/index.js#L173)).

For example:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

const state = () => ({ counter: 0 });

const mutations = {
  increase(states) {
    Vue.set(states, 'counter', states.counter + 1);
  },
};
```

Note:

- I use variable name *states* rather than *state* on function *increase* on purpose, because variable *state* may be defined in upper scope (like my example above). If not rename first mutations's argument to "*states*" (or other name), it breaks rule [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-shadow).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to alter the rules of the Airbnb config you can do the following:`

```
mutations: {
    increase: (state) => {
        const thisState = {...state};
        thisState.counter++;
        Object.assign(state, thisState);
    }
}`
```

In the above, you make a copy of the existing state, modify the counter on that copied state, then replace the existing state with the newly updated state.